# increase performance while creating objects in php

Tags: php, mysql, performance, object

I get about 500 MySQL entries from which I create objects. I loop through each entry and create two objects of it like this:

```
foreach ($contacts as $contact){
    $contact = new ContactModel($contact);
    $company = $contact->getCompany(); //returns CompanyModel
    $html .= "The Company is:" . $company->getName();
}
```

Of course I do much more in my code like displaying the name of the contact and so

Now this takes about 30 seconds to load.

How can I increase the performance of this?

Comment: Do you have set proper indices on your database table? How does your SQL look like (please add to question)?

Comment: Your problem is not in the code you display here. A loop through 500 element just to create what appears to be simple objects does not take 30 seconds to run. As Erik says, dig in the mysql direction to find the cause of your problem

Comment: Running SQL queries in a loop is allways slow. Try to optimize the sql query.

Comment: Insert objects in batches not one by one.